# Need help regarding custom authentication firebase + php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase SDK 3.0. I need help regarding custom authentication.
I am doing custom authentication with firebase. For generating token I am using php server I am able to generate token successfully with HS256 algorithm
but when i am using that token to authenticate with firebase I am getting like this

```
{"code":"auth/invalid-custom-token","message":"The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation."}
```

response at network

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"
 }
}
```

can anyone help me to out from this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try using RS256 algorithm, because this is what the docs say.

I'm having similar problem when trying to genereate tokens from python(python-jose) and .net (jose-jwt), but I still get the same error even with RS256 (the token itself can be validated successfully via jwt.io). 
On the other hand the token generator provided in the firebase example seems to work fine with RS256(KJUR/jsrsasign). So i'm stuck with it too..

Comment: I'm having similar problems.  I'm going to reach out to support and see if they can add any clarification.